`annotate-equations` package : change arrow direction and not compatible with `babel`
First issue : the arrow direction is not modified by the line
\tikzset{annotate equations/arrow/.style={->}}

as in this MWE:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{annotate-equations}

\begin{document}
   
   \tikzset{annotate equations/arrow/.style={->}}

   Some text here, 
   $\frac{\eqnmarkbox[red]{n1}{1}}{\eqnmarkbox[blue]{d1}{3}} = 
   \frac{\eqnmarkbox[red]{n2}{2}}{\eqnmarkbox[blue]{d2}{6}}$, 
   and some other text here.
  
   \annotatetwo[yshift=.7em]{above, label above}{n1}{n2}{$\times 2$}
   \annotatetwo[yshift=-.7em]{below, label below}{d1}{d2}{$\times 2$}

\end{document}

Second issue : if I use \usepackage[french]{babel}, the annotation arrows are broken and the compilation returns errors.
Are these limitations or bugs of the annotate-equations package?
If yes, what would be the best alternative to perform the annotations in the MWE above?

Babel package for some languages (like franch) redefine meaning of TikZ internals. For returning of original meaning in tikzpicture is defined babel TikZ library:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}   % <-------

\usepackage{annotate-equations}

\begin{document}
   
   \tikzset{annotate equations/arrow/.style={->}}

   Some text here, 
   $\frac{\eqnmarkbox[red]{n1}{1}}{\eqnmarkbox[blue]{d1}{3}} = 
   \frac{\eqnmarkbox[red]{n2}{2}}{\eqnmarkbox[blue]{d2}{6}}$, 
   and some other text here.
  
   \annotatetwo[yshift=.7em]{above, label above}{n1}{n2}{$\times 2$}
   \annotatetwo[yshift=-.7em]{below, label below}{d1}{d2}{$\times 2$}

\end{document}



Thanks, this solves issue 2. I still have issue 1 though. I compiled the code on Overleaf and it shows the arrows directed as expected. So there seems to be a problem on my texlive Linux installation.

I just re-installed LaTeX on my Fedora Linux workstation and I still get the double arrows.

How should be arrows directed. As imege show, they are corectly directed: 1 x 2 = 2 and 3 x 2 = 6. I tested my MWE with MiKTeX (recent version) and with use of Overleaf service. In the boht cases rezult was the same. This means that MWE is correct. If you not get the same result as I did, than try to update your LaTeX instalation to its recent version.

The main issue of my question was: I get get arrows on both sides, not in one direction. My system is always fully updated. LaTeX installation is performed with sudo dnf install texlive-scheme-basic texstudio texlive-collection-latexextra texlive-babel-french texlive-annotate-equations.

@macxpat, as you see, my MWE works fine in my local MiKTeX instalation as well in Overleaf (which use texlive, I think). So, your problem is not caused by code in my MWE. It seeems that you have some mess in your LaTeX instalation or is source in part of code you not show in your MWE.  Sory, your problem is not posible to reproduce. Just currius, do you test my MWE as it is (without any changes), as fresh document? What you got as result?
